# Discard computations for extra global work id's in OpenCL

Tags: c, opencl, gpu

I am a beginner in OpenCL and trying to use GPU for parallel processing of data sets. These datasets are of different sizes ranging from 10 to 10000 and same kernel is invoked for these sets one by one by. The problem size for each invocation is equal to the `set_size'
The kernel code contains:

```
int id = get_global_id(0);
result = Process dataset[id]
output[id] = result;
```

`output` is a global array to get back the results.

I have a GPU with 6 compute units and max `local_group_size` of 256. For fair distribution of work items, I use `local_group_size=64` and set the global work size as:

```
local_work_groups=set_size / local_group_size; 
if (set_size % local_work_size) != 0
   local_work_groups++;
global_work_size=local_work_groups*local_group_size;
....
....
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue,kernel,1,NULL,&global_work_size,local_group_size,0,NULL,NULL);
```

Only one dimension is used for both local and global NDRange. The confusion is that what if a `set_size=120`?
If `local_group_size=64` and `global_work_size=128` is used, then what will happen when a thread gets `id=121`. There is no `121th` element in the input dataset. And how will it treat `output[121]`?

Would I need to declare `output[global_work_size]` instead of `output[set_size]` and also pad the input with extra random 8 data values? Can I discard these 8 extra results within the kernel without using conditional check or barrier?
Please advise if am missing something.

Comment: You can simply add a `if(id >= size ){return;}` at the beggining of the kernel. Also, I think CL is not a good way of processing your data, since it is small and variable. A work of <100 items is typically not worth to process on GPU, unless each of the items involves ultraexpensive computing.

Comment: Yes, worked that out earlier. but thanks anyway. Seems like the performance is slow with this implementation on GPU.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using opencl >= 2.0, passing NULL as the local work group size will allow the implementation to split up the workgroups into non uniform sizes (ie maintaining optimum performance with no code modifications). This is supported by intel and AMD, though not nvidia. Under opencl <= 1.2, this will produce poor performance

If you're running under opencl <= 1.2, your options are sadly to either pad your global worksize buffer and ignore the extra calculated data, or to insert a conditional check into the kernel to eliminate invalid threads. For kernels of a medium size, this is normally fast enough that it should not be a problem.